# Is the similarity transform used in Kalman decomposition orthogonal?

Tags: control-theory, orthogonal-matrices, linear-control

In control theory, the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition) is used to decompose a system, so the observable and controllable states can be distinguished between the unobservable and uncontrollable states.

Consider the following discrete time system
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= Ax_k + Bu_k \\
y_k &= Cx_k + Du_k
\end{align}

The Kalman decomposition is given by $\hat{A} = TAT^{-1}$, $\hat{B}=TB$, $\hat{C}=CT^{-1}$, and $\hat{D} = D$ where $T^{-1}$ is an $n \times n$ invertable matrix. The resulting matrices $\hat{A}$, $\hat{B}$, $\hat{C}$, and $\hat{D}$ have a block structure corresponding to the controllable, observable, uncontrollable, and unobservable states. Now, my question is the following:

**Is the transpose of the similarity transform equal to the inverse $T^{-1} = T^T$?**

I have looked through several control theory books, and the decomposition is written as described previous, but I have seen from several sources that the decomposition is written with $T^T$ instead of $T^{-1}$. For example, see the [function in MATLAB for performing the Kalman decomposition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/obsvf.html#bq1nofl-1). The resulting similarity transform uses a transpose instead of an inverse. Similarly, the book ["Modern Control Theory" by Brogan](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Brogan-Modern-Control-Theory-3rd-Edition/PGM135781.html) uses a transpose instead of an inverse as well.

Comment: No, In general $T^{-1} \neq T^{T}$. However, you can choose a $T$ that has this property. For example, choose a set of vectors that span the null space of the observability matrix, and are linearly independent with norm 1. Let these vectors be the columns of the matrix $T_1$. Then select the remaining vectors to complete the basis that are linearly independent with norm 1. Let these vectors be the columns of the matrix $T_2$. Then the matrix T = [T1, T2] is an orthogonal matrix and $T^{-1} = T^{T}$. This matrix will create a block structure for the observable states.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve Thanks! I see. So, if I am understanding, we can always construct an orthogonal $T$ (as you described), but $T$ being orthogonal is not necessary. Is that right? This seem sufficient for an answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix